# Devaney chaos and topological entropy

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, chaos

I am searching for dynamical systems on compact spaces which are Devaney chaotic but have topological entropy zero. On the interval such systems do not exist. I think on the Cantor space and on the torus it should be possible to construct such systems, but I do not find a reference to such results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of a dynamical system exhibiting Devaney chaos with zero topological entropy is constructed in the paper ["Entropy and Exact Devaney Chaos on Totally Regular Continua"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.6017.pdf). The key ideas behind the construction are outlined below.

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. The goal is to define a continuous map $f: X \rightarrow X$ that is Devaney chaotic yet has topological entropy $h(f) = 0$.

For $f$ to be Devaney chaotic means satisfying:

1. $f$ has a dense set of periodic points.
2. $f$ is topologically transitive.
3. $f$ displays sensitive dependence on initial conditions.

It's shown such an $f$ cannot exist when $X$ is the unit interval. Instead, $X$ is taken as a totally regular continuum. Conditions are derived under which P-Lipschitz maps on such spaces can achieve zero entropy.

In particular, $A$ be a finite splitting of $X$. For a P-Lipschitz map $f$, the topological entropy is bounded by:

$h(f) \leq \log^+ L_B + 2\theta_B \log^+ L_A$

Here, $L_A = \max_{A \in A} L_A$ is the maximal Lipschitz constant over $A \in A$, $L_B = \max_{A \in B} L_A$ for $B \subseteq A$, and $\theta_B$ quantifies asymptotic transition frequencies in the graph $G_f$ of $f$.

By carefully selecting the Lipschitz constants $\{L_A\}$ and frequencies $\theta_B$, the author shows that it may be possible to construct $f$ satisfying conditions 1), 2), and 3) while still having $h(f) = 0$. I am not sure of an actual explicit construction of such a function but there are other examples of such functions where the Devaney chaos condition is slightly relaxed (e.g. see ["Exact Devaney chaos and entropy"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/bf02972670)).

Comment: Many thanks for the link. Also a reference in the paper is helpful to get such systems on the cantor fan.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly easy to make such a system symbolically (i.e. on the Cantor set), but I'm not sure of examples in print. Here is the simplest one I could think of.
Our system $(X, T)$ will be a subshift, meaning that $X \subset A^\mathbb{Z}$ for some finite alphabet $A$ (here $A = \{0,1\}$), the dynamics $T$ are given by the left shift map, and $X$ is closed and $T$-invariant.

We recursively define sets $A_k$ of $0$-$1$ words, beginning with $A_0 = \{0,1\}$.
We will see from the definition that $|A_k| = k+2$ for all $k$. Our recursive rule is: for all $k$, if $A_k = \{w_1, \ldots, w_{k+2}\}$, then
$A_{k+1} = \{w_1^{k+2}, w_2^{k+2}, \ldots, w_m^{k+2}, w_1 w_2 w_3 \ldots w_{k+2}\}$, where $w^i$ is shorthand for the concatenation $ww\ldots w$ of $i$ copies of $w$. For example, $A_1 = \{00, 11, 01\}$ and $A_2 = \{000000, 111111, 010101, 001101\}$. Define $X$ to be the subshift consisting of all $x \in \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ in which every subword of $x$ is a subword of some word in $A_k$ for some $k$.

We first claim that $X$ has dense periodic points. To see this, assume that $v$ is a word in the language of $X$, i.e. some $x \in X$ contains $v$. Then by definition, there exists $k$ and $w \in A_k$ so that $w$ contains $v$ as a subword. By definition, $A_{k+1}$ contains $w^{k+2}$, $A_{k+2}$ contains $(w^{k+2})^{k+3} = w^{(k+2)(k+3)}$, etc. This means that the infinite periodic sequence $\ldots www \ldots \in X$, since every subword of it is a subword of $w^m$ for some $m$, which is itself in $A_{n}$ for large enough $n$. Since $w$ was arbitrary, periodic points of $X$ are dense.

To see that $X$ is transitive, let's denote, for each $k$, $v_k$ by the word in $A_k$ which is the concatenation of all words from $A_{k-1}$ (rather than just a power of one). Clearly $v_k$ is a subword of $v_{k+1}$ for all $k$, so we can take a limit of the $v_k$ to obtain $z \in X$ which contains all $v_k$. Since each $v_{k+1}$ contains all words in $A_k$ as subwords, $z$ contains every word in every $A_k$, and so by definition of $X$ it has dense orbit.

Sensitive dependence is known for all subshifts without isolated points. The key is that the usual metric on $X$ is $d(x,y) = 2^{-k}$, where $k$ is the minimum absolute value of a coordinate $i$ where $x(i) \neq y(i)$.
In particular, for any $x \neq y$, there is $i$ s.t. $x(i) \neq y(i)$, then
$(T^i x)(0) \neq (T^i y)(0)$, so $d(T^i x, T^i y) = 1$. Now, for any $x \in X$, you can find arbitrarily close $y$ not equal to $x$ (if $x$ is periodic, take an appropriate shift of $z$ above, and if $x$ is not periodic, take a very close periodic points). By the above argument, some shifts of $x,y$ have distance $1$, verifying sensitive dependence.

The entropy of any subshift $X$ is given by the exponential growth rate of the number of words in the language of $X$ as a function of length. In other words, $h(X) = \lim_n \frac{1}{n} \log |L_n(X)|$, where $L_n(X)$ is the set of $n$-letter subwords of points of $X$.

A simple induction shows that all words in $A_k$ have length $(k+1)!$, and we recall that $|A_k| = k + 2$ for all $k$. Now, for any $n$, take the minimal $k$ so that $n \leq (k+1)!$; then $n > k!$. Since every word in every $L_m(X)$ for $m \geq k$ is a concatenation of words in $A_k$, and since $n < (k+1)!$, every $w \in L_n(X)$ is a subword of a concatenation of two words in $A_k$. It is therefore determined by those two words, and the location within the first word at which $w$ begins. Therefore, $|L_n(X)| \leq (k+2)^2 (k+1)! = (k+1)(k^2)^2 k!$. It's clear that for large $k$, $(k+1)(k+2)^2$ is much smaller than $k!$, which in turn is smaller than $n$. So, for large $n$, $|L_n(X)| \leq n^2$, which means that $h(X) \leq \lim_n \frac{\log(n^2)}{n} = 0$.

Comment: Many thanks for Your detailed construction. I had the (very vague) idea that something like this could be possible.